# Why my Arc Theme doesn't look right on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

I installed Xubuntu 16.04 in vmware.

I wanted a pretty theme and installed [Arc theme](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme)

I ran

```
apt-get install libgtk-3-dev autoconf automake
```

Because it is Xfce, I disabled some features and installed:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --disable-gnome-shell --disable-unity --disable-metacity --disable-cinnamon
sudo make install
```

#### But doing this has just made my window backgrounds black

[image: customise dialog]

[image: desktop]

#### In contrast, here's the official pic:

[image: desktop]

How do I apply the theme correctly?

Comment: It is not the same theme, yet the same answer applies to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189711/installing-an-xfce-theme-it-does-not-show-up

It is `Settings -> Window Manager -> Style`

not `Apprearance -> style`